# Customizing \chapter command

Tags: sectioning, graphics, xetex, chapters, titlesec

Here is the picture:

[image]

The code is from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1319/showcase-of-beautiful-typography-done-in-tex-friends?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) post.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond 12 Regular}
\newfontfamily\cmaiusc[LetterSpace=40,WordSpace=2,RawFeature={+swsh,+dlig}]{EB Garamond 12 SC}

% Environments
\usepackage{setspace}
\newenvironment{comment}
  {\begin{spacing}{0.8}\itshape\scriptsize\hspace{-1em}}
  {\end{spacing}}

\newcommand{\bbook}[4][]{%
                        \makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=6in]{#4}}
                        \chapter[#1]{#2,\\\large #3\\\char"2766}
                        \thispagestyle{empty}
                        \begin{center}
                        {\cmaiusc capitolo\ \roman{chapter}}.
                        \end{center}
}

\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]%
   {\centering\huge}%
   {}%
   {0pt}%
   {}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{5pt}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage\noindent                                      % from here
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

\bbook{Analysis mathematica}{principia.}{genese_heading}
\begin{center}
\parbox{4.65in}{
\begin{comment}
comment
\end{comment}
}
\end{center}

\end{minipage}

\vspace{\baselineskip}                                         % to here

\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Is possible replace the `\bbook` command in this code with the classic `\chapter` command but that incorporate all the code enclosed into the "from here" "to here" besides the commands of `\bbook`. So the "new" `\chapter` command should have four arguments, if is possible in the order shown below. In this example:

```
\chapter{genese_heading}{Analysis mathematica}{principia.}{comment}
```

I would that the "new" command `\chapter` goes into the headers and the `\tableofcontents` as the normal chapter command, but only with the second argument of it, in this example: "Analysis mathematica"

Comment: Please always [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) using backticks `\`` to  as I did in my edit.

Comment: Don't do it. Many LaTeX functions rely on the original syntax of `\chapter`.

Comment: @egreg oh, thanks, however is possible that the first argument of `\bbook` go into the headers and `\tableofcontents` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest this strategy:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\newfontface\cmaiusc[LetterSpace=40,WordSpace=2,RawFeature={+swsh,+dlig}]{EB Garamond Regular SmallCaps}

% Environments
\usepackage{setspace}
\newenvironment{chaptercomment}
  {\centering
   \begin{minipage}{.8\textwidth}
   \centering
   \begin{spacing}{0.8}
   \itshape\scriptsize\ignorespaces}
  {\end{spacing}\end{minipage}\par\bigskip}

\newcommand{\Chapter}[4][]{%
   \chapter[\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax#2\else#1\fi]{%
     \makebox[\textwidth][c]{\includegraphics[width=6in]{#4}}\\
     #2,\\\large #3\\\char"2766}
   \thispagestyle{empty}
   \begin{center}
     \cmaiusc capitolo\ \roman{chapter}.
   \end{center}
}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]%
   {\centering\huge}%
   {}%
   {-40pt}%
   {}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{5pt}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\Chapter{Analysis mathematica}{principia.}{genese_heading}

\begin{chaptercomment}
\lipsum[2]
\end{chaptercomment}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

The input is simpler than before and the markup clearer.

If you say

```
\Chapter[Short title]{Long title}{subtitle}{image}
```

then "Short title" will go in the TOC and the headings, as usual, otherwise "Long title" will be used.

Comment: Thanks ! perfect ! is possible choose the `\char"2766` for each chapter separately? and make the title of chapter in the table of contents in small caps like the memoir class ?

Comment: @FormlessCloud To make title of chapter in Table of Contents small caps, use following code: ``\chapter*{Heading for chapter printed on page} \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\textsc{Small Caps Title in ToC}}``